# Установка сессии

Tags: php, mysql

Мне нужно поставить сессии но не удается, что делать? Это файл для закачки файлов "обработчик".

```
<?
    #Просто начальная информация.
    #Нужно назвать таблицу.
    $table="files";
    #Сервер, на котором находится база
    $dbhost="localhost";
    #Имя базы данных на сервере
    $dbname="Maxim";
    #Пароль к базе.
    $dbpass="Maxim757377m";
    #Имя конкретной базы данных
    $dbbase="host1235767";

    //Теперь подсоединяемся к базе
    $connect = mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbname", "$dbpass");
    mysql_select_db($dbbase, $connect);

    $id = (isset($_GET['id']))? intval($_GET['id']): false;

    if(!$id) echo 'ERROR';

    //Увеличиваем количество кликов по определенному url.
    //При этом id указывает на нужную запись.
    if(!isset($_SESSION['download'][$id])){
    mysql_query ("update $table set download = download + 1, href = href where id='$id'");
    $_SESSION['download'][$id] = $id;
    }

    //Теперь достаем url и делаем туда редирект
    $query = "select * from $table where id='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $tab=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $href=$tab["href"];
    header("location: $href");
    ?>
```

Comment: >Мне нужно поставить сессии **но не удается** 

больше информации

Comment: база данных? файл который отправляет запрос?
по крайней мере это весь файл обработчика

Comment: что именно не удается.

Comment: а ну да, у вас тут сессиями и не пахнет ) ниже ответ.

Comment: коменты в стиле перла, нет session_start... Попытка реализовать какуето магию в sql запросах... Ососбенно тут мне нравится<br>
<br>
    `href = href where id='$id'`<br>
<br>это гениально ^^

Comment: так было написано в статье

Comment: Вот ссылка на статью http://www.comprog.ru/PHP/article_2195.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это файл отправляющий запрос обработчику

```
<? 
    session_start();
    include("blocks/bd.php"); 
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {$id = $_GET['id'];}
    if (!isset($id)) {header("Location: files.php");}
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE id='$id'",$db);
    if (!$result)
    {
    echo "<p>Запрос из базы данных не прошел!<br> Код ошибки:</p>";
    exit (mysql_error());
    }
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if(!isset($_SESSION['view'][$id])){
    mysql_query ("UPDATE files SET view= view + 1 WHERE id='".$id."'",$db); 
    $_SESSION['view'][$id] = $id;
    }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<p>Информация не может быть извлечена</p>";
    exit();
    }
    ...
    .....
    printf ("<div class='view_news_title'>%s</div><a href='files_add/'><img style='margin-left:590px; margin-bottom:-50px; padding-top:10px;' src=\"images/add_files.png\" onmouseover=\"this.src='images/add_files1.png';\" 
    onmouseout=\"this.src='images/add_files.png';\"></a><div class='view_news_author'>Автор: %s</div><div class='view_news_date'>Дата: %s</div><div class='view_news_body'>%s</div><a href='download.php?id=%s'><img style='margin-left:15px;' src=\"img/dowload_button.png\" onmouseover=\"this.src='img/dowload_button2.png';\" 
    onmouseout=\"this.src='img/dowload_button.png';\"></a><div class='view_news_viewers'>%s Просмотров: %s</div>",$myrow['title'],$myrow['author'],$myrow['date'],$myrow['text'],$myrow['href'],$myrow['download'],$myrow['view']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую [почитать](http://zavu.ru/itqCoT2/)
после прочтения все станет ясно.

Comment: вы не поняли мне нужно чтоб мне кто тоошибку исправил

Comment: ок, ожидайте, щас прибудет исправляющий телепат.

Comment: а шуточки в стиле "я тупой(т.е вы)" не надо тут показывать

Comment: да я уже решил проблему вам не скажу

Comment: можете закрывать тему

Comment: это не проблема, можете унести тайну с собой :)